# unexpected T_STRING?

Tags: php, foreach

I'm getting "syntax error, unexpected T_STRING" on this line and can't locate the culprit. Searched google, this forum, etc. and still stuck.

```
foreach($result in $results){
```

In this block:

```
<?php
  $results = mysql_fetch_array($row_rsCategories);
  $filters = array();

  foreach($result in $results){
    // assuming each result has an array of filters
    $filters = array_merge($filters, $result['filter']);
  }

  $filters = array_unique($filters);
  $csFilters = implode(',',$filters);
?>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`foreach` in PHP works the way round. It's

```
foreach ($results as $result) //...
```

Comment: Great input, and a lot very quickly, thanks much all! Selected this one as it addressed the line in question - wish I could accept more than one!

Answer (score 4):

```
$results mysql_fetch_array($row_rsCategories);
```

is missing an `=` for assignment. PHP, in its infinite wisdom, [decides that you want a string](http://codepad.org/xU66dH3c).

Comment: Fixed @minty, still getting the error.

Comment: @Gary: The other one is what Johannes answered with. `foreach ($results as $result)`, though, rather than `for`.

Comment: Corrected in my answer, thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Actually it's just related to PHPs tokenizer. WHen parsing the script, all lines are first split into tokens. There are multiple types - and those are the types that appear in error messages when PHP finds syntax errors. One of those types is T_STRING. It matches everything that has not been matched by any other type - this is why most syntax errors specify that one. SO what the error message tells you is: "Ey, tokenizer got me a T_STRING token here, but that doesn't make any sense".

Comment: @JohannesH.: Yes, and it acts that way because of PHP’s silly implicit strings. :(

Comment: Yep, whoever wrote that tokenizer was lazy. There could easily be T_UNMATCHED or something. But instead, they considered that a feater and put it in the spec, so nobody can ever get rid of it :D

Answer (score 1):

"Unexpected string" errors in PHP are strange things. They often do not actually indicate what looks like a string in your code.

This is because of how PHP treats constants. `FOOBAR` could be a constant, for instance, as could any sequence of letters that doesn't represent something else, like a class name or a keyword. But, if it hasn't been defined, PHP treats it as the string `'FOOBAR'`. This is silly behaviour, but there we go. That's PHP for you.

The reason you are getting this error is because `in` is not a keyword (see the [list of keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) in the manual). Nor is it a class name (though it could be). It has no inherent meaning in PHP. So PHP sees it, and thinks "aha, you clearly want the string `'in'`." So your code effectively looks like this:

```
foreach($result 'in' $results){
```

PHP now says, "Oh, but you can't have a string here!" This is obviously true. What is not obvious, however, is why PHP's designers decided that the most useful message at this point would be to say that there was an unexpected string. Very misleading!

But the problem, as indicated elsewhere, is that you are trying to do a Javascript loop:

```
for (result in results) {
```

Where you are aiming for a PHP loop:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
```

Comment: Thank you @lonesomeday for explaining the how & why, and the link - both help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the equal (=) operator after $results on the first line

it should be

```
    <?php
  $results = mysql_fetch_array($row_rsCategories);
  $filters = array();

  foreach($results as $result){
    // assuming each result has an array of filters
    $filters = array_merge($filters, $result['filter']);
  }

  $filters = array_unique($filters);
  $csFilters = implode(',',$filters);
?>
```

Also replace "in" with "as" inside the foreach statement.